# How can I set the Accelerometer Sensor Range?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms, linux, sensors

The Accelerometer Sensor is set to a Range of 2 - 4 g on most devices.
There is no option to turn it up to 8 or 16 G, which my sensor and most others are capable of.
I found some information but can't get any further how to achieve this.

I have the LIS3DSH Sensor in my Xiaomi Device.

There is a manual which states that in the configuration `.hal` file you can set:

```
/* ACCELEROMETER SENSOR \*/
#define SENSOR_ACC_LABEL “LSM303DLHC 3-axis Accelerometer“
#define SENSOR_ACC_INCLUDE_FILE_NAME “lsm303dlhc.h“
#define SENSOR_DATANAME_ACCELEROMETER LSM303DLHC_ACC_DEV_NAME
#define ACCEL_DELAY_FILE_NAME “pollrate_ms“
#define ACCEL_ENABLE_FILE_NAME “enable_device”
#define ACCEL_RANGE_FILE_NAME “range”
#define ACCEL_MAX_RANGE 16*GRAVITY_EARTH
#define ACCEL_MAX_ODR 400
#define ACCEL_POWER_CONSUMPTION 0.033f
#define ACCEL_DEFAULT_FULLSCALE 4
```

But I have no idea how to do this.

Resources to read:

- [Hardware abstraction layer for Android](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00063297.pdf)
- [Android accelerometer full range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280924/android-accelerometer-full-range/30332888#30332888)

I would be really glad if someone knows the way to go, or point me in the right direction for further research.